# How to open local file from Tide SDK app

Tags: javascript, windows, html, tidesdk

I am building an windows app using Tide SDK. How can I open a local file from my app. For example, I have a pdf file somewhere in my harddisk. I put the link to that file to my app. When I click on the link, I want it to open the pdf file using default programm associated with pdf type file.

If it is not possible then I have one more general question. Is it possible to access local file system by any app that built using html5 and javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**we can access  local file system in tidesdk application.**

See the following code.

```
var contents;      
var file= 'test.txt';      
var Dir = Ti.Filesystem.getUserDirectory();        
var readfi= Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Dir, file);      
if (readfi.exists())
{     
   var Stream = Ti.Filesystem.getFileStream(readFi);    
   Stream.open(Ti.Filesystem.MODE_READ);     
   contents =Stream.read();  
   alert( contents );  
   Stream.close();    
}
```

The above code will read the text file and alert the content. Visit  [here](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Filesystem.File)  to know tidesdk file system.

**Following code will open the given URL in default browser.**

```
Ti.Platform.openURL('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

**Following code will Open the given application or file in the system's default program.**

```
Ti.Platform.openApplication('C:/Documents and Settings/Thavamani00/Desktop/readme.txt');
Ti.Platform.openApplication('C:/Documents and Settings/Thavamani00/Desktop/cart15.png');
```

The above code displays the text file in notepad and displays the image in mircosoft picture manager.

it works well for me.i hope its your required answer.

Comment: your solution will read the file content and show it. What I need is clicking a file link, it will be open by associated application. For example, clicking on a pdf file link will open the file with adobe acrobat reader, text file with notepad, html file with firefox browser and so on...

Comment: Mr sparrow its possible.i edited my post there you can get solution to your problem.

Comment: Ti.Filesystem.getFileStream(readFi); this line has typo 'readfi' it should be. :)

Comment: Is it possible to edit this to get an images' src data as opposed to just reading a text file?